# How can I import a Role to use to create CodeBuild project in AWS CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk

I would like to import a Role in CDK to use it to configure a new CodeBuild project.

```
const role1 = Role.import(this, "service-role", {
      roleArn: "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/service-role/codebuild-manualproject-service-role" ,
    });
```

NOTE:  I change the Account Ref in the Arn for security.

Here is the code for creating the codebuild project ..

```
        // Create build
        // note: now that there is one bucket per build project it is not necessary to have a prefix/subdirectory in the bucket for storing cache items
        const project =  new codebuild.Project(this, CODEBUILD_PROJECT_NAME, {
          // render url for build badge
          badge: true,
          cacheBucket: cacheBucket,
          cacheDir: "Cache",
           description: "An AWS codebuild project for repo: " + REPO + ", created: " + Date(),
          // note will use standard buildspec.yml
          // set the environment
          environment: {
            buildImage: CODEBUILD_IMAGE,
            computeType: CODEBUILD_COMPUTETYPE,
          },
          projectName: CODEBUILD_PROJECT_NAME,
          role: role1,
          // add in source control
          source: source,
          // set timeout - mins
          timeout: 30,
          vpc: vpc,
         securityGroups: [securityGroup]
      });
```

I run ..

```
npm run build
```

no errors

I then run

```
cdk synth
```

Got the error ..

```
Error: Validation failed with the following errors:
  [Quicktest2Stack/frontend-v3-codebuild/PolicyDocument] Policy must be attached to at least one principal: user, group or role
    at Synthesizer.synthesize (C:\scratch\CDKTest\quicktest2\node_modules\@aws-cdk\cdk\lib\synthesis.js:22:23)
    at App.run (C:\scratch\CDKTest\quicktest2\node_modules\@aws-cdk\cdk\lib\app.js:44:31)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\scratch\CDKTest\quicktest2\node_modules\@aws-cdk\cdk\lib\app.js:24:51)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:284:20)
    at process.emit (events.js:196:13)
Subprocess exited with error 1
```

So if I "import" the role in CDK and attempt to bind it to the new CodeBuild project then it fails (cdk synth)

But it I allow CDK to create it's own role when building the new CodeBuild project then cdk synth works and the stack can be deployed BUT the codebuild project fails.

If I take the CodeBuild project and just manually change the role to the inital one I tried to import - then all works well and can build will run.

I need to be able to create the CodeBuild project **and** bind to the role in via CDK.

CDK VERSION: 0.28.0

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem disappeared once I upgraded CDK to 0.31.0.